# copyrighted material used by a commercial entity

Tags: copyright

Can a copyrighted material be used by a company employees if it is not a part of a commercial product?

Comment: What do you mean by "used"? The answer is likely to depend on it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert indeed.  In addition, as I am sure you are aware, it will also depend on whether the company has a license for the intended use of the copyright material or owns the copyright itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which "commercial" is relevant to copyright. First, it might be a factor in a software license, for example "may only be used for non-commercial purposes". This is most often found on free or discount software, so you would have to look at the exact wording of the license.

The second is, in the US, one can "use" (copy) protected items to a limited extent if that usage is "fair use". For example, you can copy a sentence of two from a novel in a review of the novel, without obtaining permission of the copyright owner. The distinction between a non-commercial purpose and a commercial purpose figures into the determination of "fair use", whereby a commercial use is less likely to be considered "fair use". There isn't a distinction between the bosses use and an employee's use, that is, being the boss does not change your rights w.r.t. fair use.

Whether or not a "use" potentially infringes copyright depends on the specific action that constitutes the use. Copyright restricts copying. You may use a printed book as a weight – that does not infringe copyright. If a computer has a program installed on it, anyone can "use" that copy, because they are not making another copy. You cannot freely use the installation media to install it on another computer without a license to do so, so you have to check whether e.g. only the boss can install the program on his computer, or can employees do likewise (an individual license vs. a site license).

Comment: "a commercial use is less likely to be considered "fair use"": but it should be underscored that "less likely" isn't the same as "unlikely," as in the given example of a review.  "If a computer has a program installed on it, anyone can "use" that copy": commercial licenses are frequently more restrictive.